# Representing share on histogram axes respect to total data points - also ones not in range (fraction of values respect to ALL points)

Tags: plotting, legending, histograms

I want to tick the Y axes so that the heights of the displayed bins *in range*, represent the share *respect to total available points*.

I have a distribution of percentages on N data points (see below for clarity).

- I want to plot only the ones falling within range 0 - 1. (100%), in bins of 0.1; values > 1. will not be plotted;
- I want to tick on the Y Axes the percentage representing how many points a bin represent, respect to total points

---

Example:

`x` is the data below.

`Histogram[x]` shows all points. I want only a range, so:

`Histogram[x, {0, 1., .1}]` that shows only two bins, one with 6 values, and one with 3.

Now, I want to report ticks on the Y axes to mark the height of the bars, as relative percentage to the total available points.

So the maximum Y' could be:

```
Total[Select[# < 1. &]@x]/Length[x]
```

that is, the number of values displayed in the histogram, respect to total (I don't see values of `x` not in range).

In percentage, a max value of Y axes would be ~2% of total values:

```
Round[Total[Select[# < 1. &]@x]/Length[x] * 100]
```

How to tick the Y axes with percentages from 0 to 2% , indicating the height of bins as "share" respect to total points ?

---

I looked at https://stackoverflow.com/a/7708628/305883.

I understood that `"probability"` will use the fraction of values respect to the values displayed in the histogram, and won't count for values out of range.

Did I understand correctly?

Answer of @JimB shows a simpler direction, but I am confused:
the sum of bins' frequency does not match with the sum the number of values in range: `Total[Select[# < 1. &]@x]/Length[x]`

(in the example from suggested answer: `0.0146341 + 0.00731707 != Total[Select[# < 1. &]@x]/Length[x]` )

I received feedback to improve my question, so I edited it and I hope it is clearer now.

I leave my previous attempt for learning.

---

**First attempt to mark percentage on Y axes, to indicate % of values represented by bars respect to total points.**

```
(* here I try to compute the share of a values on Y axes respect to title size of my sampling, including values not in Range *)
bins = {Range[0, 1, 0.1]};
Histogram[x, bins, "Probability", 
 Ticks -> {First@bins, 
   Table[{0.01 i, 
     If[Mod[i, 10] == 0 ToString[i /Length[x]*100 // N] <> "%", 
      i]}, {i, 100}]}]
```

**Second attempt**

```
(* here I save heights repsect to histogram where I display all values, and then use my own bins between 0, 1. *)

{bins, heights} = HistogramList[x];

bins = {Range[0, 1, 0.1]};
Histogram[x, bins, "Probability", 
 Ticks -> {First@bins, 
   Table[{0.01 i, 
     If[Mod[i, 10] == 0 ToString[i /Total[heights]*100 // N] <> "%", 
      i]}, {i, 100}]}]
```

**data**

```
x = {2.09143, 1.57714, 2.91429, 1.2, 1.57714, 1.78286, 1.57714, 1.54286, \
1.11429, 2.05714, 2.22857, 1.54286, 1.71429, 2.70857, 2.57143, \
6.17143, 2.05714, 1.02857, 1.30286, 1.61143, 1.71429, 1.2, 2.48571, \
1.54286, 3.63429, 1.64571, 1.23429, 2.43429, 1.88571, 2.22857, \
2.05714, 1.2, 1.88571, 1.33714, 1.54286, 1.71429, 2.22857, 1.88571, \
2.57143, 2.22857, 1.30286, 2.57143, 5.00571, 6.51429, 2.4, 2.46857, \
1.54286, 1.98857, 1.88571, 2.14286, 2.4, 2.57143, 2.57143, 1.54286, \
1.37143, 1.54286, 2.05714, 2.02286, 1.50857, 2.22857, 2.22857, \
1.54286, 1.71429, 1.13143, 1.45714, 1.71429, 1.71429, 2.57143, \
1.62857, 2.26286, 2.57143, 0.857143, 2.91429, 1.30286, 1.66286, \
2.22857, 1.95429, 1.88571, 1.68, 1.88571, 2.53714, 1.2, 1.85143, \
2.74286, 1.71429, 2.22857, 2.4, 2.4, 1.54286, 1.2, 1.71429, 1.88571, \
1.54286, 1.71429, 2.05714, 1.81714, 1.57714, 1.88571, 1.45714, \
1.62857, 1.78286, 1.56, 1.54286, 1.30286, 1.88571, 2.05714, 1.64571, \
2.05714, 1.81714, 2.22857, 1.81714, 2.4, 1.45714, 2.4, 2.48571, \
1.88571, 1.71429, 1.71429, 1.2, 1.30286, 1.13143, 2.05714, 2.22857, \
1.2, 1.23429, 2.22857, 1.37143, 1.09714, 1.09714, 1.09714, 1.2, \
2.22857, 2.31429, 2.22857, 2.57143, 2.4, 2.4, 2.05714, 2.05714, \
3.42857, 1.37143, 2.57143, 1.68, 1.73143, 0.685714, 1.02857, 1.02857, \
1.68, 1.2, 1.71429, 1.71429, 1.47429, 2.22857, 1.02857, 1.37143, \
2.74286, 1.54286, 1.2, 1.2, 1.54286, 2.05714, 3.80571, 1.2, 2.74286, \
2.05714, 2.05714, 1.30286, 2.22857, 2.57143, 2.74286, 1.71429, \
1.54286, 1.2, 1.09714, 1.88571, 1.95429, 1.2, 1.37143, 1.2, 1.23429, \
1.44, 1.2, 1.2, 2.22857, 1.37143, 2.4, 1.71429, 1.71429, 1.37143, \
0.685714, 1.88571, 1.54286, 1.88571, 1.57714, 1.57714, 2.22857, \
1.40571, 1.2, 1.2, 2.91429, 1.88571, 1.88571, 0.685714, 1.2, 1.57714, \
1.57714, 2.14286, 1.71429, 0.685714, 2.14286, 1.09714, 0.685714, \
2.05714, 1.02857, 1.37143, 1.81714, 1.81714, 1.95429, 1.95429, \
1.30286, 2.4, 1.26857, 1.54286, 1.54286, 2.33143, 1.37143, 1.71429, \
1.47429, 2.22857, 1.71429, 1.71429, 1.98857, 2.05714, 1.81714, \
1.54286, 1.02857, 2.05714, 1.54286, 1.37143, 1.37143, 1.88571, \
1.37143, 2.33143, 2.05714, 1.92, 1.88571, 1.54286, 1.2, 2.22857, \
2.74286, 2.22857, 1.37143, 1.71429, 2.05714, 1.88571, 1.71429, \
1.54286, 1.2, 1.37143, 1.30286, 1.68, 1.71429, 0.857143, 1.2, \
1.37143, 1.23429, 1.23429, 1.71429, 2.09143, 1.02857, 1.88571, \
3.08571, 1.88571, 1.37143, 1.2, 2.05714, 1.28571, 2.22857, 1.28571, \
1.71429, 2.4, 1.37143, 2.05714, 1.2, 1.71429, 1.71429, 2.05714, \
1.54286, 1.37143, 1.71429, 2.4, 2.05714, 2.22857, 1.30286, 1.88571, \
1.02857, 1.71429, 1.37143, 2.05714, 2.4, 1.54286, 1.11429, 1.71429, \
1.37143, 2.05714, 1.62857, 1.71429, 1.64571, 2.4, 1.71429, 2.05714, \
1.13143, 0.891429, 1.54286, 1.54286, 2.05714, 2.22857, 1.88571, \
1.02857, 1.54286, 1.37143, 2.05714, 1.95429, 1.28571, 1.28571, \
1.54286, 1.54286, 1.71429, 1.71429, 1.64571, 2.05714, 1.47429, \
1.88571, 2.29714, 1.02857, 1.2, 1.54286, 1.02857, 1.71429, 1.54286, \
1.71429, 1.68, 1.71429, 1.54286, 0.685714, 1.47429, 1.71429, 1.88571, \
1.54286, 1.54286, 1.2, 1.13143, 1.37143, 2.31429, 2.31429, 1.88571, \
2.05714, 2.05714, 2.05714, 1.37143, 1.71429, 1.71429, 1.71429, \
1.37143, 1.02857, 1.88571, 1.88571, 2.05714, 2.74286, 1.71429, \
1.71429, 1.71429, 2.02286, 1.57714, 1.37143, 1.26857, 1.37143, \
1.88571, 1.64571, 1.37143, 2.05714, 1.54286, 1.2, 1.88571, 2.05714, \
1.54286, 1.02857, 1.02857, 1.71429, 1.61143, 1.71429, 1.71429, \
1.37143, 1.30286, 1.71429, 1.37143, 1.54286, 1.88571, 1.37143, \
1.88571, 1.68, 2.05714, 1.37143, 2.4, 1.37143, 1.37143, 1.37143, \
1.54286, 1.68, 1.18286}

Histogram[x, {0, 1, 0.1}]
```

Comment: The option is `"Probability"` and not `Probability`.

Comment: you're right @Jim but does not change results - still can't see share ticks on axes

Comment: Understood.  But not seeing desired ticks is not in your question.  Please make your question explicit in the question rather than in the comments.  I'm not trying to be picky as the reason for this forum is to provide an answer for you AND for others who might have the same question.  But when the question is unclear or keeps changing, then that will not likely help anyone else.

Comment: It seems the only difference in the current answer I provided below is that the vertical axis is a "proportion" and you want "percentage".  I'll make that change.  However, your formula for comparing the proportion of points less than 1 is incorrect:  `Total[Select[# < 1. &]@x]/Length[x]` should be `N[Length[Select[# < 1. &]@x]/Length[x]]`.  Using the correct formula matches what I provided.

Comment: ouch, sure. Thank you again @JimB for taking time to check on my question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not at all certain what you're asking but here is one interpretation.

First, here is a histogram of the complete dataset:

```
Histogram[x, Automatic, "Probability", PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True]
```

[image: Histogram of all data]

Now here is that same histogram but only showing part of the horizontal axis:

```
Histogram[x, Automatic, "Probability", PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.02}},
 Frame -> True, PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, -0.01}, {0, 0}}]
```

[image: Histogram with restricted range]

**Update:**

If the vertical axis needs to be a percentage rather than a proportion, then I don't see that `Histogram` has such an option.  Maybe the use of the `ScalingFunctions` option might do it but I did not have success with that.  The brute-force alternative is to relabel the vertical axis with your own ticks.  (I also matched the binwidth to what was requested in the question.)

```
ticks = {{Table[
  If[OddQ[i], {i/1000., "", {0.01, 0}},
   {i/1000., NumberForm[i/10., {2, 1}], {0.015, 0}}], {i, 0, 20, 1}], 
   Automatic}, {Automatic, None}};
Histogram[x, {0.1}, "Probability", Frame -> True, 
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 0.02}}, FrameTicks -> ticks,
  PlotRangePadding -> {{Automatic, -0.01}, {0, 0}}]
```

[image: Histogram with percentage vertical scale]

Comment: thank your for your feedback @JimB: I updated the question, hope it is clearer.